# Set a variable to null whenever a user clicks the back button to a particular page in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to set a variable to set a variable to null whenever a user clicks the back button after signing in. So I am doing this but it is not working as the variable still shows on that Page which is the signin page

```
var currentUserNow = localStorage.getItem("username")
        alert(currentUserNow);
           localStorage.removeItem("userDetail");
        localStorage.removeItem("username");
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/sign-in');
```

Now I want to ask is there anyhow I can tell that the user has clicked the back button to a particular page and set that variable to null

Comment: You are talking about device back button, not the web browser back button right?

Comment: Yeah. The device back button

Comment: My challenge is how do I set a variable to null should the user clicks a back button to the signin page after login

Comment: The code you typed should be executed when the user clicks back button or?

Comment: It doesn't do that. That is why I am here

Comment: How do you invoke that code?

Comment: I think I need to make a check when the device back button is clicked. And also make a check if the url is pointing to signin. But that is the challenge now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106804/discussion-between-stjepano-and-andrea-robinson).

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to disable the back button in login page.
then try in login.html

```
<ion-content hide-back-button="true">
```